# java.lang.AssertionError: expected [201] but found [201]

Tags: rest, api, post, rest-assured

I am pretty new to testing with RestAssured and using the methods.

This is my code

```
package com.123.tests;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

public class PersonPostTest {

    @Test
    public void RegistrationSuccessful()
    {       
        RestAssured.baseURI ="https://reqres.in/api";
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();



        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name", "morpheus"); 
        obj.put("job", "leader");

        request.body(obj.toString());
        Response response = request.post("/users");

        int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, "201");
        String successCode = response.jsonPath().get("SuccessCode");
        Assert.assertEquals( "Got the correct code", successCode, "Success");
    }

}

and everything seems to be good but I get this below error.

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
FAILED: RegistrationSuccessful
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [201] but found [201]
```

I don't seem to understand what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `getStatusCode()` is Integer.
You are checking equality of `statusCode` which is Integer(`201`) with Object type. That is the issue here.
Try with below snippet. It works.

```
    Response response = request.post("/users");
    int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, 201);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for Object Types here:

```
Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, "201");
```

One is **Integer** and the other is **String**. That's the reason for failure. Make sure to convert them to the same type.
Replace the assertion with the below:

```
Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, new Integer(201));
```